# How to convert String value to date in Salesforce apex class?

Tags: apex

I tried using Date.valueOf(stringVar), but I am getting system.typeexception while saving the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to convert the value derived from Date.valueOf(stringVar) value to String value using below format,

for ex,

```
Date dateValue = Date.valueOf(stringVar);
String newValue =   dateValue.year() + '-' +  dateValue.month() + '-' +  dateValue.day();
```

then convert the new value to Date using --> Date.valueOf( newValue);

This way you might get the correct format